# Change background color of notification text of NotifyIcon Component in c#

Tags: asp.net, background-color, notifyicon

i am using NotifyIcon in my desktop .net application in c#. i can change the icon but can't change the background color of the notification text. i searched on web, couldn't find anything helpful regarding this or maybe i skipped if is there any. looking forward for help regarding this. thnx in advance :)

Comment: why `asp.net` in tags?? Anyway, you will probably need to write custom tooltip to ahcive this.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik your notify icon control uses resource image to display icon, there in no built in solution to change background color. Simpest solution is to change whole icon. Or as huMpty duMpty mentioned create your own control, which is not so easy.

Comment: and as a beginner its really hard for me to create custom tooltip for background color :( i wanted to change the background color of the notification text not the icon. anyway thnx guys

Comment: You can try to look for already customized external packages, maybe something exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use `alertcontrol(devexpress)` or `desktopcontrol(telrik)` for custom notify appearance.